# Reverse engineering for security research

Tags: copyright, eula

Is it legal to reverse engineer a closed source application in order to check how secure it is if:

- the software came preinstalled on the device (i.e. I have not signed
  an EULA)
- I have signed an EULA that forbids reverse engineering

I have seen a lot of renowned experts reverse engineer popular software and publish details on their flaws and their inner workings on conferences. Is this legal ? (I am particularly interested in EU law)

Answer (score 3):

As you have agreed, by contract, not to reverse engineer the product, technically it would be a "breach of contract" to do so, assuming such terms are enforceable where you live (or wherever the EULA selects as the choice of forum).

Comment: No, it would not be — reverse engineering may be specifically allowed by the legislature, which may preempt any terms in the contract to the contrary.

Comment: "No, it would not be" - you say it _may_ be allowed, which means it _might_ not be, not it _would_ not be. You would have to check that before starting any reverse engineering, and I think it is unlikely for the purpose of "security research" which is in practice indistinguishable from hacking.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am not a legal expert, but as I understand it, hacking your own equipment that you own is generally speaking not a crime.

Comment: @user253751 it may not be a crime, but it's probably a breach of contract.  Contrary to the implication in this question, software pre-installed on a device typically does have an EULA, and courts have found such "agreements" enforceable despite a lack of signatures.

Comment: @phoog (note: different courts have also found them unenforceable, so nobody really seems to know. Especially because you don't see the contract until after you've bought the product)